# Swift: Can not delete characters in textField with condition based character restriction

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have this condition to a textField, where -

1. If in a dropdown of countries, I select BE, then a textfield in the same form should be allowed only 4 characters
2. If it's not BE, then the textfield to be allowed only 12 characters.

I implemented this using -

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

**The problem:**

The above implementation is working good but -

1. I select a country other than BE (i.e. 12 characters allowed in textfield) and save data.
2. Re-open form and select "BE". Now I am not able to edit the text field at all.

How do I solve this problem?

**Here is my full code** -

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        var maxLength: Int?
        let newText = NSString(string: textField.text!).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        if ((textField.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage == "emoji") || (textField.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage == nil)){
            return false
        }

        switch textField {

        case postCodeText:

            if (self.selectedCountryCode == "BE") {
                maxLength = 4
            }

            else {
                maxLength = 12
            }

            return newText.characters.count <= maxLength


        case streetText:
            maxLength = 40
            return newText.characters.count <= maxLength
        }
    }
```

***EDIT 1: Added a screen recording
[recordit link demonstrating the problem](http://g.recordit.co/i0jmDDz5V7.gif)***

Comment: the backspace is working or not on textfield edit

Comment: In general, yes it is working normally... But when I try the scenario explained in "The Problem" section, the backspace doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is that whenever you choose a country just save the previous text into another String if it is necessary to store the previous record other wise just clear the `textField` every time you select a country from dropDown selection method.
Because the you choose other than BE it extend the range to 12 and you entered more than 4 characters in `textField` and when you change the country back to BE the `textField` is already have data more than the range of BE so it doesn't allow you to change text.

Below is just an example of demonstration

```
func didSelectCountryFromDropDown() {
    self.textField.text = ""

}
```